# Page URLs in ServiceWorker scope

Tags: javascript, url, service-worker

How can I get the URL of pages that register ServiceWorker in ServiceWorker scope?

#### main.js

```
console.log(window.location.pathname); // /user
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/app/sw.js',{scope : '/user'}).then(function(){
    console.log('Service Worker initialised');
}).catch(function(er){
    console.log('er.message);
});
```

#### sw.js

```
console.log(self.location.pathname); // /sw.js
// How can I get the `/user` URI?
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Within a service worker, [`self.registration.scope`](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#service-worker-registration-scope) will give you the associated scope. This is available in Chrome 42+ (which just became the stable release), so it should be safe to use.

I *think* you might also be asking about how to get the a reference to all of the active pages that a service worker controls, too? If that's the case, the answer is to use [`self.clients.matchAll()`](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#clients-getall) (also available in Chrome 42+), which will return a (potentially empty) array of [`WindowClient`](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#window-client-interface) objects, corresponding to each open, controlled page. `WindowClient` exposes a `url` property with the corresponding URL.

Comment: Thanks for your extra information. I would have never expected a reference for each page. This is extremely awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful docs on available data:

> ServiceWorkerRegistration.scope Read only
> Returns a unique identifier for a service worker registration. This must be on the same origin as the document that registers the ServiceWorker.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration

Comment: If you think that you want to comment instead of answering then please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead and delete this non-answer. If you want to answer instead of commenting please read [answer] and [edit] accordingly.